# How to display Robotframework test results summary in Slack

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, slack-api, slack

I am Using RobotFramework to execute my tests on jenkins and using slack plugin to display test execution status on slack.But i want to diplay test summary like following

```
           Total Tests : 50
           Total Passed : 40
           Total Failed : 10
```

i came through a good article for displaying cucumber tests results on slack but could not find any documentation for robotframework.
http://dev.venntro.com/2016/11/reporting-cucumber-results-in-slack/

Answer (score 3):

Slack notifications are framework and tools agnostic, meaning whatever works for cucumber or other systems is applicable to Robot Framework.

They provide a [solid api](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages) for sending messages, and I'd recommend the [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) as being both simple and powerful - an http POST payload to a specific payload turns up as a message in a channel of your choice, with support of formatting, attachments, etc.

Here's a trivial example, taken from the cited doc pages:

```
curl -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "This is posted to #general and comes from *monkey-bot*.", "channel": "#general", "link_names": 1, "username": "monkey-bot", "icon_emoji": ":monkey_face:"}' \
 https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The simplest option - which I personally use for the daily sanity run notifications - are the "Slackbot Remote Controls"; in nutshell, you enable it for an account, and by sending a POST to an endpoint, a message is delivered to the target channel - no json, no fancy stuff. Example:

```
curl --data "The full run finished against \`$current_version\`, with $number_of_failed failed cases; full results at http://the_internal_reporting_server/report.html"  \
$'https://yourdomain.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&channel=%23automation-results'
```

As you can see, the message body supports simple formatting (the ` escaping, * for bold, etc), and http links are automatically highlighted in the clients. The channel to send to is a parameter for the endpoint; can't get simpler than that :)

---

That particular example is from a bash script, thus the variables in it. Which leads to - how to get the data for the output.

Couple of options there - both the `robot`/`pybot` runner, and the `rebot` result parser return the number of failed cases as RC (return code), which can easily be gotten (`$?` in bash is the RC of the last executed command/program).

More "advanced" is to parse the output.xml file - it's fairly straightforward and well structured.
There's a top-level tag `<total>`, which holds the overall results, for example:

```
<total>
<stat fail="22" pass="849">Critical Tests</stat>
<stat fail="22" pass="849">All Tests</stat>
</total>
```

So if you parse (or grep) its "All Tests" `<stat>` child, you can get the fail/pass and the total count from it; similar for the run time.

Finally, for total control, one can use the [robot.rebot](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/autodoc/robot.html#module-robot.rebot)
 and [robot.result](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/autodoc/robot.result.html) packages, which provide full access to results, thus any output generation that is needed.

---

I've answered your question without mentioning the Jenkins Slack plugin for a couple of reasons - a) I don't have access to it (but come to think of it, I should try it out one of these days), b) it most probably provides convenience wrappers over the same slack api functionality anyways, and c) the http api is universal, thus can be used in whatever flow the company has.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who comes across a similar issue here is the solution I found for the situation.

I leveraged the [Listener Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) available in robotframework to trigger my messages to slack. Using the close method as a trigger for the slack message and end_test and end_suite methods to keep track of test and suite results in a dictionary.

The robot command then looks like the following with the URL and channel passed down with a semi-colon separator after the path to your Listener (RobotListener.py in this case):

```
robot --listener C:\Users\cullzie\RobotListener.py;https://hooks.slack.com/services/ABCDED/12345/XYZW;cullzie test_suites\
```

And the code for my listener is as follows:

```
import os
import json
import requests

from collections import Counter

class RobotListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def __init__(self, webhook_url, channel, icon=':squirrel:'):
        self.webhook_url = webhook_url
        self.channel = channel
        self.icon = icon
        self._suite_status = dict()
        self._test_status = dict()

    def end_test(self, data, result):
        self._test_status[data] = result.passed

    def end_suite(self, data, result):
        self._suite_status[data] = self._test_status
        self._test_status = dict()

    def close(self):
        attachments = self._build_overall_results_attachment()
        self._send_slack_request(attachments)

    def _build_overall_results_attachment(self):
        results = {k: v for test_results in self._suite_status.values() for k, v in test_results.iteritems()}
        return [
        {
            "pretext": "*All Results*",
            "color": "good" if all(results.values()) else "danger",
            "mrkdwn_in": [
                "pretext"
            ],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Tests Passed",
                    "value": Counter(results.values())[True],
                    "short": True
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total Tests",
                    "value": len(results.values()),
                    "short": True
                },
                {
                    "title": "Pass Percentage",
                    "value": "{0:.2f}%".format(float((Counter(results.values())[True])/float(len(results))) * 100),
                    "short": True
                },
                {
                    "title": "Results",
                    "value": os.environ['bamboo_resultsUrl'],
                    "short": True} if os.environ.get('bamboo_resultsUrl', False) else None,
            ],
        }]

    def _send_slack_request(self, attachments):
        try:
            data = {"channel": "@{0}".format(self.channel), "username": "ufgatestbot", "attachments": attachments,
                "icon_emoji": self.icon}

            response = requests.post(url=self.webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.HEADERS)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                print 'Error in sending data to Slack - Status Code: {0}, Text: {1}'.format(response.status_code,
                                                                                        response.content)
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
```

At the moment it is configured to give a link to Atlassain Bamboo test results but could easily be updated to link to Jenkins test results.

[image: Sample Slack Output]